# Flutter - Error parsing HTML data

Tags: android, html, ios, dart, flutter

I've been trying to modify the code [available here](https://github.com/Rahiche/flutter_jobs_app) so that the `title` and `dateAdded` from [VMoneyNews](https://www.virtualmoneysnews.com/category/bitcoin-news/) is visible in the apps `listView`.

Unfortunately, when I try to run the following edited code I get the error stated in the Image below.

```
http.Response response = await http.get('https://www.virtualmoneysnews.com/category/bitcoin-news/');

//parse and extract the data from the web site
dom.Document document = parser.parse(response.body);
document.getElementsByTagName('article').forEach((child) {
  jobsList.add(Job(
    title: child.getElementsByClassName('title').first.text,
    dateAdded: child.getElementsByClassName('thetime date updated').last.text,

  ));
});
```

[image: method 'trim' called on null]

Comment: What do I need to do here?

Comment: can you update the cde with the full snippet, in above one there is no trim method.

Comment: I never added a trim method, above is the only code I changed, do you recon this is the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably remove this snippet, which relies on `item.location`, which you aren't populating.

```
            Text(
              item.location.trim(),
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
```

I'd refactor the `Job` class to rename it `Article`, `Headline` or `Story` i.e. something meaningful. For example:

```
class Story {
  String title;
  String dateAdded;

  Story(this.title, this.dateAdded);

  @override
  String toString() => '$title $dateAdded';
}
```

Your scraping code could then be written:

```
http.Response response = await http
    .get('https://www.virtualmoneysnews.com/category/bitcoin-news/');
dom.Document document = parser.parse(response.body);

List<Story> stories = document
    .getElementsByTagName('article')
    .map((e) => Story(
          e.getElementsByClassName('title').first.text,
          e.getElementsByClassName('thetime date updated').last.text,
        ))
    .toList();
```

Comment: This is just what I’m looking for, thanks for the help Richard